# Given is the following empirical distribution function. Indicate which characteristic values occurred with which frequencies.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, statistics, functions

Based on this empirical distribution function, is it possible to state what the minimum sample size was ?

$F(x) = \begin{cases} 
      0 & x < 2.5 \\
      0.2 & 2.5 \leq x < 4 \\
      0.45 & 4 \leq x < 5.7 \\
      0.8 & 5.7 \leq x < 8 \\
      1 & 8 \leq x
   \end{cases}$

---

Could you tell me if what I did is correct ? I'm really unsure about this exercise

From what I understand, this empirical distribution function adds all probability until it reaches $1 = 100 \%$

It seems to me that the characteristic value $x < 2.5$ occurred with a frequency of $0$. The characteristic value $2.5 \leq x < 4$ occurred with a frequency of $0.2$, the characteristic value $4 \leq x < 5.7$ occurred with a frequency of $0.45 - 0.2 = 0.25$, the characteristic value $5.7 \leq x < 8$ occurred with a frequency of $0.8 - 0.45 = 0.35$, and $8 \leq x$ occurred with a frequency of $1 - 0.8 = 0.2$.

And for the question "Based on this empirical distribution function, is it possible to state what the minimum sample size was ?", if what I wrote above is correct, it seems the frequencies of occurrence are:

$$0, 0.2, 0.25, 0.35, 0.2$$

All those numbers can be divided by the number $0.05$, so the minimum sample size would be $1 \div 0.05 = 20$

I am really unsure about this exercise, so I would really appreciate your help. Thank you

Comment: Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the empirical frequencies must be integers divided by the sample size, your analysis is correct.  Expressed as vulgar fractions in their lowest terms the  frequencies are
$$
0,\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{4},\frac{7}{20},\frac{1}{5},0\ .
$$
The product of these frequencies and the sample size must all be integers, and the smallest positive integer $\ s\ $ for which this is the case is the least common multiple of the frequencies' denominators:
$$
s=\text{lcm}(5,4,20,5)=20\ .
$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I was really unsure about this exercise